# Shall we run the php script on .net server?

Tags: php, configuration, asp.net

**I just want to know that ,shall we run the php script on .net server or to run a php script on a .net server what configuration we required?**

Suppose i have a website developed in php environment and running successfully on my local-host now what i want ,i want to upload this site on server which supports .net scripts ,so  can you guys tell me that what configuration(like:Apache ,MySQL etc.) should be there on .net server to run a php script,is it possible to run a php & .net files on same server?

Comment: Please add some more detail about what php script? what server? you mention barely nothing useful.

Comment: @FrederikNielsen see my updated question.

Comment: @HarshalMahajan is this a 3rd-party, shared hosting plan you're using?

Comment: @gravyface ,no i am using dedicated server

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown ,i think you didn't understand what i want to know,i am much familiar with php but want to execute it on .net server.

Comment: @HarshalMahajan Amazingly, in order to interpret PHP on a Windows box (i.e. serve PHP via IIS), you need to.... install PHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide any sort of system requirements for your PHP application.  The best I can tell you is `YES` you can run PHP on IIS.

http://php.iis.net/

Comment: Thanks for reply Brent ,but can you please tell me about iis? how is this possible?

Comment: No I can't. You provide no background or information about your app, no system requirements and failed to even attempt to read any of the information from the website I provided to you.  Do your research and homework first, then post a new question with any issues or problems you run into.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is available as an extension for IIS, so you can certainly run both PHP and .NET code on the same webserver.  Take a look at http://php.iis.net/ for details.

Unfortunately as a linux admin I'm not familiar with the setup myself.